# Rails - tinytds crashing ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crash, freetds

When querying MSSQL 2008 database using freetds and tinytds gem with syntax below:

```
db = TinyTds::Client.new(:username => ...)
select = db.execute("EXEC dbo.__stored_procedure__")
db.close
```

Then this line is causing ruby to crash on windows:

```
select.each {|x| p x}
```

Strange thing, when querying simple select:

```
select = db.execute("SELECT field FROM table")
```

`select.each` doesn't crash - it doesn't do any loop either

It doesn't crash webrick nor rails console either.

But when I change code to:

```
db = TinyTds::Client.new(:username => ...)
select = []
db.execute("EXEC dbo.__stored_procedure__").each { |x|
  select << x
}
db.close
```

Then it works like a charm (even with select).

Don't how it works on os better than windows...

Comment: `select.each { |x| p |x| }` is not valid ruby. Are you sure you didn't mean `select.each { |x| p x }`?

Comment: Yes, you're right I did mean that

Answer (score 0):

Your expectations are incorrect. I suggest you read over the TinyTDS usage here.
https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds#tinytdsclient-usage

Comment: My point was that TDS can easily crash ruby. Just do something with result after closing connection. You wont't get any error - it's lack of simple connection check. I have to do it myself.